# Error while extracting a word-2007 docx using apache POI

Tags: java, apache

I tried to extract a .docx file using Apache POI as shown in below java code.

```
 XWPFDocument doc = new XWPFDocument(new ByteArrayInputStream(fileData.data));
 XWPFWordExtractor extractor = new XWPFWordExtractor(doc);
 String wordText = extractor.getText();
```

Any compilation failure couldn't found with this code but I get the following error while running the code.

```
ERROR - AsyncIndexer Error while indexing.
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument$Factory.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.onDocumentRead(XWPFDocument.java:134)
at org.apache.poi.POIXMLDocument.load(POIXMLDocument.java:159)
at org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.XWPFDocument.<init>(XWPFDocument.java:123)
at org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.impl.indexing.indexer.MSWordIndexer.getIndexedDocument(MSWordIndexer.java:32)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.solr.SolrClient.indexDocument(SolrClient.java:178)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.doWork(AsyncIndexer.java:203)
at org.wso2.carbon.registry.indexing.AsyncIndexer$IndexingTask.run(AsyncIndexer.java:189)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:441)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load SchemaTypeSystem. Unable to load class with name schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder. Make sure the generated binary files are on the classpath.
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:783)
at org.openxmlformats.schemas.wordprocessingml.x2006.main.DocumentDocument.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
... 14 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: schemaorg_apache_xmlbeans.system.sE130CAA0A01A7CDE5A2B4FEB8B311707.TypeSystemHolder
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:501)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:421)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:412)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.baseadaptor.DefaultClassLoader.loadClass(DefaultClassLoader.java:107)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:248)
at org.apache.xmlbeans.XmlBeans.typeSystemForClassLoader(XmlBeans.java:769)
... 15 more
```

I put

org.apache.xmlbeans.*,org.openxmlformats.schemas.*,org.apache.poi.xwpf.*,org.dom4j.*,

in the classpath of pom file. Can anyone help me to find the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

Does this appear, while running the code inside of eclipse or from command line?

Did you try to run "update maven project" and "run as -> maven install"?

Answer (score 0):

I tried to run this using maven clean install in command line.